# Should I choose Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I want to use Drupal as a Framework for my application. Apart some modules, such as Image, Imagecache, Views, and Panels, I will make custom modules. I need the best performance and result.

What version of Drupal should I use?

Comment: I am on the final portion of an involved Drupal 7 site. The other night I installed Drupal 6 on my development machine because I wanted to see how a D6 only module worked. Wow! I was so happy to be on D7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if in general purposes one version can have better performance than the other, depending on the focus of your application and the specific plugins you will work with you may find that a specific version more suitable for you (even if it is not in general terms). If performance is a big issue for you, you may want to do specific tests for your application. In [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) we package both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 so you could use them (the packages are completely free) for comparing both version in the environment that you prefer, locally (native or in a vm) or in the cloud. The two versions of Drupal that we package are self-contained and packaged with the same dependencies (same version of Apache, PHP and MySQL). This is important because you will comparing the application itself, without depending on the environment you are using. This will make easier for you to focus on the tasks of testing the Drupal performance.

You can check [this link](http://drupal.org/node/648458) for some recommendations for testing Drupal performance. Please notice that the latest Drupal Devel module (released on 07/2011) doesn't include performance feature so you would need to use an earlier version.

Answer (score 8):

While Drupal 7 is probably the "right" thing to do, there are a few good reasons to stick with Drupal 6.

One is the status of the modules you need.  Drupal 7 versions will be less mature than their Drupal 6.  They may have better features, but may also have bugs.  Some just don't have Drupal 7 versions yet.  You need to go through your modules and make this assessment yourself.

The other is how much legacy code you wish to reuse.  Yes, you can port, but that leads me to my next point.

Most of the projects I work on are sites for clients, and are firm-fixed-cost and firm-schedule.  In my case, I have to be conservative with third-part module choices.  My clients don't care if a project is late because of a bug in a module.  In their eyes, that is my responsibility.  Yes, I can debug modules and provide patches.  But, this takes time and   maintainers don't always accept patches.

All of this weighs into the version choice decision.

Answer (score 3):

If the main focus of what you are going to use is Image, ImageCache, Views and Panels I think you will find 7 and the modules needed stable enough.

I like module development in 7 more than 6, there's just so many more interesting things that can be accomplished.  All the capabilities you need for handling Images is built in and I can vouch that what I use Views for works just fine.  Panels is very actively being developed on 7 and is probably ready especially since you sound like you can handle workarounds and possibly fixing anything broken and contributing the fixes back.

Go for 7.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with D7 if I were you. Taxonomy and CCK are in core in D7 and Views is really stable in my experience, even though there's only a release candidate at the moment.

Do not underestimate upgrading a site from D6 to D7. Yes, it is possible, but you want to save yourself a couple of headaches and start with D7 right away.

Drupal 7 is [much more scalable](http://drupalwatchdog.com/1/1/performance-scalability-drupal-7) and since you're planning a huge site, you're going to need that.

You write that you will be hosting documents; does that mean that you're storing the document contents in the database, or are you hosting downloadable files like .pdf's and .doc's? D7 is much better for managing files, as is explained in this [Acquia blog post](http://acquia.com/blog/drupal-7-file-system-changes).

Comment: They'll be pdf files or in other formats on the disk and not in the database. I want to go with D6 to get smooth and quick start. Also lot of documentation and books are already available for D6.

Comment: If you made up your mind and decided to go with Drupal 6, I will not stop you. IMHO there are plenty of [D7 books](http://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+7+books&tbm=shop) and documentation. Also keep in mind that the amount of support, new features and bugfixes for D6 will slowly decrease over the coming years. D6 may provide a slighty smoother start (I'm not even sure about that) but don't forget the long-term planning.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

- D7 support upgrade from D6
- Entity concept (see commerce module apply it)
- CCK (Field API) move to core
- Now D7 is stable for production
- Views 3 support
- Entity API is flexible to write new entity type (commerce, rules)
- Many module upgrade to D7, see at http://drupalcontribstatus.com/
- Performance

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Drupal 7.

It is newer and therefore reasonable to say improved over Drupal 6.  It will also provide for longer support time as the newer release.

One reason you may want to go with Drupal 6 is if you're in need of a particular module that is not available in Drupal 7, but many popular modules have been or are being ported over to Drupal 7.